# If $V$ is a $K$-Vector Space then V is a $\mathbb{M}_n(K)$-Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $K$ a Field and $V$ a $K$-vector-space of dimension $n$ with basis fixed $\alpha$, we define for a matrix  $A \in \mathbb{M}_n(K)$ and a vector  $v \in V$ the product  $A \cdot v$ as the only vector $w \in V$ such that  $[w]_\alpha=A[v]_\alpha$. then  $V$ is a $\mathbb{M}_n(K)$-module with the sum of vectors and the product defined.

My try

Let $A \in \mathbb{M}_n(K) $ and $u,v \in V$

then $A \cdot(v+u)=x+y=Av+Au$ because

$A[v+u]_{\alpha}=[x+y]_{\alpha}=[x]_{\alpha}+[y]_{\alpha}$

but im stuck from here any help?

Comment: Why not just proceed with the other axioms?

Comment: @azif00 im confused in how to approach for example to show that $(A+B)v=Av+Bv$ foe example if i take Av=w and Bv=z then $A[v]_{\alpha}+B[v]_{\alpha}=[w]_{\alpha}+[z]_{\alpha}=[w+z]_{\alpha}=(A+B)[v]_{\alpha}$ ?

Comment: @azif00 is that right?

Comment: It is. You can also observe that $$[(A+B)v]_\alpha = (A+B)[v]_\alpha = A[v]_\alpha + B[v]_\alpha = [Av]_\alpha+[Bv]_\alpha = [Av+Bv]_\alpha,$$ from which follows that $(A+B)v = Av+Bv$.

Answer (score 0):

This is all quite easy. It's just a matter of notations. I propose the following notations :

$(K,V,+,.)$ is a $K-$vector space.
$\mathbb{M}_n(K)$ is a non-commutative ring. We want to show that :
$$(\mathbb{M}_n(K), V,+,*)$$
is a module, where $\forall A\in \mathbb{M}_n(K), \forall v\in V, A*v$ is defined as the only vector $w\in V$ such that $[w]_\alpha=A[v]_\alpha$. So, we have :$$[A*v]_\alpha=A[v]_\alpha$$

1. Let us show for example that $A*(u+v)=A*u+A*v :$

By definition, $A*(u+v)$ is the only $w$ s.t. $[w]_\alpha=A[u+v]_\alpha$.

$A[u+v]_\alpha=A([u]_\alpha+[v]_\alpha)=A[u]_\alpha+A[v]_\alpha=[A*u]_\alpha+[A*v]_\alpha=[A*u+A*v]_\alpha$

So, $A*(u+v)=A*u+A*v$

2. Let us show that $(A+B)*v=A*v+B*v$ :

$[A*v+B*v]_\alpha=[A*v]_\alpha+[B*v]_\alpha=A[v]_\alpha+B[v]_\alpha=(A+B)[v]_\alpha=:[(A+B)*v]_\alpha$

So, $(A+B)*v=A*v+B*v$

3. $[I_n*v]_\alpha:=I_n[v]_\alpha=[v]_\alpha$

So, $I_n*v=v$

4. And so on, with the other axioms.